# Undefined index: transaction_id

Tags: laravel

> Undefined index: transaction_id
> #0 C:\app\Http\Controllers\SendMoneyController.php(190): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8,
> 'Undefined index...', 'C:\\...', 190, Array)

Can someone help me, I encounter this error.

This is where the error comes from `'transaction_id' => $transactionResponse['transaction_id']`

```
public function submitPaymentMethod ( Request $request )
{
    // we'll get all the data we need for us to be able to use the transactionService
    $paymentMethodId = $request->input('payment_method_id');        
    $recipientId = $request->input('recipient_id');
    $countryFromId = $request->input('country_from_id');
    $countryToId = $request->input('country_to_id');
    $amountSend = $request->input('sent_amount');
    $payOutNetworkId = $request->input('pay_out_network_id');
    $userCurrencyCode = $request->input('user_currency_code');
    $recipientCurrencyCode = $request->input('recipient_currency_code');
    $countryNameTo = $request->input('user_country_name');
    $countryNameFrom = $request->input('recipient_country_name');
    $countryPayOutNetworkId = $request->input('country_pay_out_networks_id');
    $stripeToken = $request->input('stripe_token');

    // we'll use the newly make service transactionService that will handle all transaction related
    // such as handling in stripe and saving in db, then pass it to a variable
    $transactionResponse = $this->transactionService->submitPayment( $stripeToken, $paymentMethodId, $recipientId, $countryFromId, $countryToId, $amountSend, $payOutNetworkId, $userCurrencyCode, $recipientCurrencyCode, $countryNameTo, $countryNameFrom, $countryPayOutNetworkId );
    // we'll then return that transactionService return for us to display in front
    return response()->json([
        'success' => $transactionResponse['success'],
        'message' => $transactionResponse['message'],
        'transaction_id' => $transactionResponse['transaction_id']
    ], 200);
}
```

Why the error is undefined index? Thank you

Comment: hello, try dumping value of `$transactionResponse`. the response may not contain value.  you can use `dd($transactionResponse);` to print values in that object. or try using die(json_encode($transactionResponse));

Comment: if you `dd($transactionResponse)` , what is the output ?

Comment: it says that no such fee exist in our record. but in my seeder. the fee is nullable so the fee can  be null right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty basic error to track down. undefined index means you are trying to access an index of an array which does not exist. Which means you are not even checking the response before handing it off.

```
        return response()->json([
            'success' => isset($transactionResponse['success']) ? $transactionResponse['success'] : false,
            'message' => isset($transactionResponse['message']) ? $transactionResponse['message'] : '',
            'transaction_id' => isset($transactionResponse['transaction_id']) ? $transactionResponse['transaction_id'] : null
        ], 200);
```